# Installing specific version of legacy Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am looking forward to installing a specific version of the Microsoft Edge browser (44.17763.1.0). Any idea where I can find this specific version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy version of Edge browser is dependent on the windows build version.

As far as I know, the Windows 1809 OS installed the Edge 44.17763 version. You could try to use this version of Windows OS.