# How to install specific version of microsoft edge browser?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

How to install specific version - Microsoft Edge 41.16299.1480.0 browser on windows 10

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267283/installing-specific-version-of-legacy-edge-browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to install the specific version of the MS Edge legacy browser.

MS Edge (EdgeHTML) legacy browser by default comes with the Windows 10 OS.

So there is no separate installation setup available for it.

Note that the current latest version of MS Edge (EdgeHTML) legacy browser is around 44.x

It gets updated with the Windows OS updates. So if your Windows OS has the latest updates installed then you cannot downgrade the version of the MS Edge (EdgeHTML) legacy browser.

So if you are not on that version then there is no way to move to that version.

But Microsoft provides the free virtual machines to make a test with the browsers like IE and MS Edge (EdgeHTML) browser.

[Windows 10 virtual machine](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

You can try to create a VM and make a test on it.